# Передать значения в value в action="?"

Tags: javascript, html

как в форме при выборе option у `select` передать значения в `value` в `action="?"`
пример:

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <select name="content" onChange="this.form.submit()">
        <option value="index1.php">1</option>
        <option value="index2.php">2</option>
        <option value="index2.php">3</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

В простейшем случае так:

```
<select onchange="this.form.action = '/'+this.value; this.form.submit();">
  <option value="">index</option>
  <option value="index2.php">index2</option>
  <option value="index3.php">index3</option>
</select>
```

У формы есть свойство **`action`**, которое можно изменить, просто изменив его, как и  любое другое свойство :) Обратите внимае на **`this.form`** - в отличие от **`.parentNode`**, всегда ссылается на форму, в которой лежит **`select`**.

Если форма лежит в другой части документа - добавим ей **`id="myForm"`** и изменим **`select`**:

```
<select onchange="var f=document.getElementById('myForm');f.action='/'+this.value;f.submit();">
```

Comment: спасибо большое! а как это все сделать без формы?

Comment: что значит без формы ? ajax ?

Comment: @amf1k, еще проще :)

    <select onchange="top.location.href='/'+this.value;">

Comment: <select  onchange="window.location = this.value">